# How to set up the required meta data for WCF restful service?

Tags: wcf, wcf-rest

I am trying to get my first WCF restful service to work.  But I keep getting a warning when i run it through VS2013.  it says it cannot find any service metadata.

How do i set this up?

The App.config file is as follows,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->


  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfJsonRestService.Service1">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8732/service1"

                  binding="webHttpBinding"

                  contract="WcfJsonRestService.IService1"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>


</configuration>
```

The IService1.cs

```
namespace WcfJsonRestService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        Service1.Person GetData(string id);
    }
}
```

The Service1.cs

```
namespace WcfJsonRestService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in both code and config file together.
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            UriTemplate = "data/{id}")]
        public Person GetData(string id)
        {
            // lookup person with the requested id 
            return new Person()
            {
                Id = Convert.ToInt32(id),
                Name = "Leo Messi"
            };
        }

        public class Person
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13771501/vs2012-wcf-rest-service-error-cannot-obtain-metadata

Comment: Please read [ask] and include the actual, full error and share your research.

Comment: As @CodeCaster linked answer says, for REST there is no metadata.  most likely if you're running it through VS it's using the WCF Test Client, which does not support REST, only SOAP.